# PEAR DB breaks PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pear

I'm working on an integration project on an existing codebase, switching to a more modern standard is not an option, the website works fine on it's live server and it's test server.

However I seem to be having trouble getting it working locally, I am using MAMP Pro, I have the PHP version set to 5.2.17 for this project as its codebase is quite old.

I have error reporting turned on, however, I get a completely blank page without even any errors displaying, and I can't trace it to anything since it's not reporting anything to the log or screen, I have traced it down to:

`$db = DB::Connect($dsn, false);`

However not sure how else I can proceed to try and get it working since not getting any error messages, I have the standard error check for this extension below, however if you attempt to print after this it doesn't print anything, if I add an echo and exit above I can see the output.

This is the package: http://pear.php.net/package/DB

Kind of stuck at this point, does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: did you turn on display_errors as well? error_reporting is fine, but you still need to actually display the errors.

Comment: Hello yes, display errors is on as well as error reporting, as I mentioned if i uncomment the line then i get errors saying that the class is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the issue was, I was not setting up the PEAR include path.